# Octet-stream to PNG

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I convert BLOB data:application/octet-stream;base64 to data:image/png;base64 ?

The image are shown anyway but the browser doesn't let me to open the image in new tab with right click.

```
$http({
    url: image,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).then((resp)=>{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        $scope.model.view.image = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(resp.data);
});
```

Comment: `result.replace('data:application/octet-stream', 'data:image/png')` ?

Comment: haha, definitely not

Comment: Why not? https://jsfiddle.net/cb78q272/

Comment: Looks like was replaced but I need a more clearly method instead of put the browser to find a pattern in that long result. To run this action consecutively maybe the browser get LAG(like my console), but thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use base64, will be problematic if it's a very long url... instead use the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL

$http({
  url: image,
  responseType: 'blob'
}).then(blob => {
  // change the type
  blob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'image/png'})
  $scope.model.view.image = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
})
```

Comment: Yep, it's working well and fast. But the "Open image in new tab" option are still not working, only when I paste the url in a new tab and hit enter. I will try to find a way to solve it. Thank you :)